# multiple arguments to logging.debug

Tags: string, python-2.7, logging

Python 2.7

I am currently using multiple lines of code for logging, as below:

```
timestr = time.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
print timestr
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(name)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s',
                    datefmt='%m-%d %H:%M',
                    filename='D://my_code_3/logging/'+timestr+'_XFR.log',
                    filemode='w')
#define a Handler which writes INFO messages or higher to the sys.stderr
console = logging.StreamHandler()
console.setLevel(logging.INFO)
#set a format which is simpler for console use
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(name)-12s: %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
#tell the handler to use this format
console.setFormatter(formatter)
#add the handler to the root logger
logging.getLogger('').addHandler(console)

name = raw_input("Please enter your name.")
print 'Hi ', name, 'Please go ahead and transfer files - Press Enter'
print
#####
now = datetime.datetime.now()
logging.debug ('File was transferred by:')
logging.debug(name)
logging.debug('The transfer took palce on:')
logging.info(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))
```

I like to rather use a single line some what similar to:

```
logging.debug (('File was transferred by:'), name)
```

But this syntax is wrong.
Please help me get this right.
/or, please suggest me another method to stream data to log file only / to console and log file both.

many thanks.
+

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use string formatting

```
logging.debug ('File was transferred by: {}'.format(name))
```

That's clean and readable

Or `logging.debug ('File was transferred by: %s' % name)`

You can read more about it [Python format string syntax docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

Comment: `@ vinny`: thanks.  It works right.  
I will need to read the ref you have provided to find correct syntax for the `logging.debug('The transfer took palce on:')
logging.info(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"))`

Comment: basically, you put a placerholder `{}` and provide what to be put in there in the `format()` method

Comment: `@vinny`:  I want to replace **print** method by **logging.info()** in the following example:
`print 'str1', var, 'str2'`
`I tried logging.info('str1{}'.var.'str2{}')`
This is not right, still looking in the documentation!

Comment: -1. This approach will perform formatting even when debug level is off. Please use format string and positional args according to this -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

Answer (score 4):

```
# Use python3 f-string, it has better syntax
logging.debug(f'File was transferred by: {name}')
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: -1. This approach will perform formatting even when debug level is off. Please use format string and positional args according to this -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

Answer (score 1):

Please use format string as a message and pass extra arguments to `debug` message.

From here -> https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug

> debug(msg, *args, **kwargs)
>
> Logs a message with level DEBUG on this
> logger. The msg is the message format string, and the args are the
> arguments which are merged into msg using the string formatting
> operator. (Note that this means that you can use keywords in the
> format string, together with a single dictionary argument.) No %
> formatting operation is performed on msg when no args are supplied.

So, in your case:

```
logging.debug('File was transferred by: %s', name)
```